# Problema con migracion en sistema programado bajo php y codeigniter

Tags: sql, postgresql, codeigniter

llevo unos dias realizando la migracion de un sistema.. el sistema tiene 4 servidores, yo estoy moviendo todo a uno que monte con WHM.
En una cuenta tengo los 4 servidores y asi ahorro el pago de 1 VPS por cada subdominio, por asi decirlo, el servidor cuenta con "Nautilus", "Api", "Reportes", "Clientes".
Estos subdominio son un VPS cada uno, por eso surgio la idea de montar un servidor cpanel propio y dejarlos todos juntos.
El problema que con el sistema de "Reportes" tengo un error que no he podido solucionar.
Les dejo un link con el archivo del proyecto https://github.com/maikelyordancl/reportes

El problema por lo que he estudiado y haciendo pruebas es porque tengo una base de datos en DIGITAL OCEAN y esta base de datos tiene conexiones "Pool". Yo monte un servidor especifico de base de datos postgresql y no tengo para hacer conexiones "Pool" pero por mi experiencia se que eso no es necesario, pero para que me entiendan:
Tengo este codigo que es para conectar a la base de datos, cuando cambio los datos logicamente yo no tengo pool "CARTOLA-POOL" por ende pongo la base de datos directo, los otros 3 sistemas funcionan sin problema, pero este se traba. No hay caso... por alguna razon es como si necesitara que fuera "CARTOLA-POOL".
Alguna idea?

```
if (ENVIRONMENT == 'production') {
$db['intranet_aicapitals'] = array(
    'dsn'   => 'pgsql:host=db-master-aicapitals-do-user-3147676-0.a.db.ondigitalocean.com;port=25061;dbname=CARTOLA-POOL;sslmode=require',
    'username' => 'cartola',
    'password' => 'xxxx',
    'dbdriver' => 'pdo',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

Comment: Para mi, no se si alguien va a poder darte una respuesta. Es como que falta una tonelada de informacion. por ejemplo.. decis que se traba.. a que te referis con eso??? igual, esto parece mas un problema de despliegue que de programacion...

Comment: se traba porque no toma la base de datos.. es como si necesitara que se llamara "CARTOLA-POOL"